How to preserve document structure in mindee docTR
Im using docTR to extract text from a pdf and then put the data in a database. for example if the pdf is like this :
Image
docTR needs to preserve the same structure so i can easily extract data but i get outputs like these :
1) 

ABC Receipt 
Nature of request 
Request Code
status of application 

aaaaa

2543522

rejected 

observation abc

2) 

ABC Receipt 
Nature of request 
aaaaa
Request Code
2543522
status of application 
rejected 
observation abc

These outputs make it difficult for me to extract data with regex (I'm doing the data extraction in java not python) so how to get the desired output ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It helps if you provide a sample as then we can use a true source rather than emulate a possibly different order. However trying your input with docTR we can see results are all spread out in a very loose order.

I am using experience to say the PDF was either written by a report system that has a tabular methodology, thus OCR did not alter the underlay, or the OCR is trying to make a table (which images nor PDF would have). Thus writes the label words first, followed by the perceived entries.
The simplest solution is to run a shell extraction as laid out by OCR, here to console, but that can be redirected to filename or memory or any second line in your choice of code. Other options are available.
For example, with poppler pdftotext (often found in Python systems). Here I just called an executable.
pdftotext -nopgbrk -layout abcreceipt.pdf -

                                   ABC RECEIPT




Nature of Request:     aaaaa



Request Code : 2543522



status of application : rejected



Observation   : abc

Using text parsing to remove white space from above the first pass might be,
ABC RECEIPT
Nature of Request: aaaaa
Request Code : 2543522
status of application : rejected
Observation : abc

But note the problem with Request:. It will need a second parse to add a space to correct to Request :
Thus without Python and without Java (just using Windows OS) I can in 4 lines get a rational output, for separation into left and right variables.
ABC RECEIPT
Nature of Request : aaaaa
Request Code : 2543522
status of application : rejected
Observation : abc

You can actually short circuit the PDF phase and just run your test image so tesseract image.png output --psm 6 will produce the compact text with just the one correction needed.
output.txt
ABC RECEIPT
Nature of Request: aaaaa
Request Code : 2543522
status of application : rejected
Observation : abc

Simply needs the extra space added same as above so the whole job can be done in one line of command coding, unless you want more as input to your functions like align the :.
tesseract image.png temp --psm 6 && for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:"  %f in (temp.txt) do if %g. == . ( echo %f >output.txt ) ELSE ( echo %f :%g ) >>output.txt

Result
ABC RECEIPT
Nature of Request : aaaaa
Request Code  : 2543522
status of application  : rejected
Observation  : abc

